# How to resolve a "malformed project" build error when building a Flutter iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have taken over a project and find myself facing this issue. How can I resolve it?:

> The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h"
> is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and
> "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
> membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in
> targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file
> in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone de Eric in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 7ZM5A78359
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           33,0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2021-05-13 14:35:48.251 xcodebuild[47387:355803] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2021-05-13 14:35:48.251 xcodebuild[47387:355803] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2021-05-13 14:35:48.251 xcodebuild[47387:355803] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2021-05-13 14:35:48.251 xcodebuild[47387:355803] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2021-05-13 14:35:48.251 xcodebuild[47387:355803] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2021-05-13 14:35:48.251 xcodebuild[47387:355803] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2021-05-13 14:35:48.251 xcodebuild[47387:355803] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2021-05-13 14:35:48.251 xcodebuild[47387:355803] warning:  The file reference for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h" is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:66013:32: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
        rc = defragmentPage(pPage, MIN(4, pPage->nFree - (2+nByte)));
                                   ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:66737:43: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MAX' [-Wambiguous-macro]
          char *zFullPathname = sqlite3Malloc(MAX(nFullPathname,nFilename));
                                              ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:218:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MAX'
    #define MAX(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14251:10: note: other definition of 'MAX'
    # define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:69397:11: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MAX' [-Wambiguous-macro]
        amt = MAX(0, (int)(pCur->pPage->aDataEnd - pCur->info.pPayload));
              ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:218:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MAX'
    #define MAX(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14251:10: note: other definition of 'MAX'
    # define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:71527:16: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
        int nAdd = MIN(nNew,iOld-iNew);
                   ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:73098:24: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'const sqlite3_int64' (aka 'const long long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            x2.nData = pX->nKey;
                     ~ ~~~~^~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:75112:21: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
      const int nCopy = MIN(nSrcPgsz, nDestPgsz);
                        ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:75386:18: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
              iEnd = MIN(PENDING_BYTE + pgszDest, iSize);
                     ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:76760:49: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MAX' [-Wambiguous-macro]
        if( sqlite3VdbeMemClearAndResize(pMem, (int)MAX(nAlloc,32)) ){
                                                    ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:218:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MAX'
    #define MAX(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14251:10: note: other definition of 'MAX'
    # define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:82139:22: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
              int nCmp = MIN(mem1.n, pRhs->n);
                         ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:82167:22: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
              int nCmp = MIN(nStr, pRhs->n);
                         ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:82356:12: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
        nCmp = MIN( pPKey2->aMem[0].n, nStr );
               ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:84362:42: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'sqlite3_uint64' (aka 'unsigned long long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        rc = sqlite3_bind_zeroblob(pStmt, i, n);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~           ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:88296:21: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'i64' (aka 'long long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        pOut->u.nZero = nZero;
                      ~ ^~~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:94211:28: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MAX' [-Wambiguous-macro]
          sqlite3_int64 nNew = MAX(128, 2*(sqlite3_int64)p->nAlloc);
                               ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:218:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MAX'
    #define MAX(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14251:10: note: other definition of 'MAX'
    # define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:94215:19: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'sqlite3_int64' (aka 'long long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
          p->nAlloc = nNew;
                    ~ ^~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:94491:25: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
      res = memcmp(v1, v2, (MIN(n1, n2) - 13)/2);
                            ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:94673:17: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
          mxCache = MIN(mxCache, SQLITE_MAX_PMASZ);
                    ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:94674:28: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MAX' [-Wambiguous-macro]
          pSorter->mxPmaSize = MAX(pSorter->mnPmaSize, (int)mxCache);
                               ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:218:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MAX'
    #define MAX(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14251:10: note: other definition of 'MAX'
    # define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:95506:45: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            iListOff = (u8*)pSorter->list.pList - pSorter->list.aMemory;
                     ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:95517:26: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'sqlite3_int64' (aka 'long long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
          pSorter->nMemory = nNew;
                           ~ ^~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:95671:19: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MAX' [-Wambiguous-macro]
        pIncr->mxSz = MAX(pTask->pSorter->mxKeysize+9,pTask->pSorter->mxPmaSize/2);
                      ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:218:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MAX'
    #define MAX(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14251:10: note: other definition of 'MAX'
    # define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:96124:21: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
              nReader = MIN(pTask->nPMA - i, SORTER_MAX_MERGE_COUNT);
                        ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:96980:17: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
        int nCopy = MIN(nRead, (p->nChunkSize - iChunkOffset));
                    ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    
             ^
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'share' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'package_info' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'keyboard_utils' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'image_downloader' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'image_cropper' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'flutter_custom_dialog' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase: /Users/splitti1/Projects/wiikko/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone de Eric.
```

Flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale
    fr-CD)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/splitti1/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (5 months ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/splitti1/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[!] VS Code (version 1.56.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone de Eric (mobile)    • 1a046776b311b2ca3539147a23be1abc00ce4dee •
      ios • iOS 12.5.2
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 4C0D6598-33D1-46B3-8871-9EEC509C33F4     •
      ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by taping

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean
flutter run
```